# How to wait until base64 encoding is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to put image file encoded into base64, put it in an object(responseData), and res.json(responseData).

The problem is that response is sent before base64 encoding is finished.
How can I delay sending response until encoding is finished.

P.S I'm not sure if sending an image in a json file is the right way.

```
  router.get("/", async (req, res) => {

    let responseData;

    await Story.find().then(storiesData => {
      responseData = [...storiesData];

      storiesData.map((storyData, storyIndex) => {
        responseData[storyIndex].imageFiles = [];

        gfs.files
          .find({ _id: { $in: storyData.image } })
          .toArray((err, files) => {
            files.map((file, imageIndex) => {
              let data = [];

              var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
                _id: file._id
              });

              readstream.on("data", chunk => {
                data.push(chunk);
              });

              readstream.on("end", () => {
                imageData = Buffer.concat(data);
                responseData[storyIndex].imageFiles[imageIndex] = new Buffer(
                  imageData
                ).toString("base64");
              });
            });
          });
      });
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
    res.json(responseData);
  });
```

Comment: The only asynchronous function in the post is the second argument in the `router.get`  call. **none of the other arrow functions are asynchronous**. Sadly there appears to be no code structure to  wait for any single file to finish being read, let alone waiting for all of them. Unfortunately it looks like a code re-write, and SO is not a code writing service...

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {

    let responseData, storiesData;

    storiesData = await Story.find();
    responseData = [...storiesData];

    const mapResults = storiesData.map((storyData, storyIndex) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            responseData[storyIndex].imageFiles = [];

            gfs.files
                .find({_id: {$in: storyData.image}})
                .toArray((err, files) => {
                    files.map((file, imageIndex) => {
                        let data = [];

                        var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
                            _id: file._id
                        });

                        readstream.on("data", chunk => {
                            data.push(chunk);
                        });

                        readstream.on("end", () => {
                            imageData = Buffer.concat(data);
                            responseData[storyIndex].imageFiles[imageIndex] = new Buffer(
                                imageData
                            ).toString("base64");

                            resolve(responseData[storyIndex])
                        });
                    });
                });

            })
        })

    const results = await Promise.all(mapResults);
    res.json(results);
});
```

The map is returning an array of promises, so after each one is done, it sends the responseData, check if final result is like you wanted if not adjust to your needs but the overall idea is there.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If it works, upvotes and mark as correct are appreciated :D