# What is the most elegant approch to waiting until a loop ends and than do an operation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, loops

I have a for loop in which I iterate over a set of around 50 object that I got from a json. In each iteration I create an object and push it into an array. My intentions are that after the for loop ends, my array is also complete, and now I would like to push this array as part of an object into a mongoose collection.

Problem is of course that when writing it in a synchronizes way I will push an empty array to Mongo as it doesn't wait for the loop to end. 
Now, What I did previously was something ugly. I waited for i in the for loop to be the array.length - 1 and then I pushed handled the pushing to DB part. 
The problem here is that it is very hacky + it does not guarantee that I got all of the results as  iteration array.length - 1 can run before array.length - 3 due to JS asynchronous nature, but I didn't mind about it back than.

Now I need to have all of the iterations inside my array.

```
    fetch("https://api.com/something/"
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => {
    let arrayToFill = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let objectToFillTheArrayWith;
        objectData = data[i];
        // Inside the for loop I make an async call to my DB for info
        Game.findOne({ "address": objectData.address })
          .then(existingGame => {
              if (!existingGame) {
                objectToFillTheArrayWith = {
                  title: objectData.name,
                  description: objectData.description,
                  image: objectData.featured_image_url,
                  price: objectData.stats.market_cap
                }
                arrayToFill.push(objectToFillTheArrayWith);
              }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            next(err)
          });
      }       
    let searchObjectDocument = {
      name: "Games",
      results: arrayToFill
    }
    // As you can understand, right now the results key value is an empty array
    new SearchObject(searchObjectDocument).save();
    // ...
```

Is there a known and intuitive solution for this? Something not really hacky as waiting for i to be array.length -1 or maybe even initiating a counter and wait until the counter is the same as the array's length -1 and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this question, and all of these kinds of questions on S.O., is to look at the forest and not the trees. Starting at the top-level, all you really need is this:

```
fetch("https://api.com/something/")
.then(r => r.json())
.then(data => {
    // convert data into a list of games
}).then(games => {
    let searchObjectDocument = {
        name: "Games",
        results: games
    }
    return new SearchObject(searchObjectDocument).save();
}).then( // ...
```

Now that you can see how execution will flow, you can fill in the gap - how to convert an array of "data" objects into an array of query results? Hopefully you're using Bluebird, in which case a `Promise.map` is the easiest way:

```
fetch("https://api.com/something/")
.then(r => r.json())
.then(data => {
    return Promise.map(data, row => {
        return Game.findOne({ "address": row.address })
        .then(existingGame => {
            if (!existingGame) {
                return {
                  title: row.name,
                  description: row.description,
                  image: row.featured_image_url,
                  price: row.stats.market_cap
                };
            }
        });
    });
}).then(games => {
    // At this point "games" is an array, but some entries
    // are undefined (the ones where gameExisted already).
    games = games.filter(game => game);
    let searchObjectDocument = {
        name: "Games",
        results: games
    }
    return new SearchObject(searchObjectDocument).save();
}).then( // ...
```

Note that if there are 50 incoming games, you are making *50 concurrent requests* to your database here. That might be fine, but in general, you want to make sure that the client you are using has a built-in throttle, or add one in yourself. (Bluebird offers an easy-to-use [concurrency option](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) for cases where you need to do it yourself.)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to use the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) library. Very easy and popular library.

This is an example of how you can use it

```
const async = require('async')

fetch("https://api.com/something/"
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => {
    let arrayToFill = [];
    async.forEach(data, function(item, callback){
        let objectToFillTheArrayWith;

        Game.findOne({ "address": item.address })
          .then(existingGame => {
              if (!existingGame) {
                objectToFillTheArrayWith = {
                  title: item.name,
                  description: item.description,
                  image: item.featured_image_url,
                  price: item.stats.market_cap
                }
                arrayToFill.push(objectToFillTheArrayWith);
              }

             // When the async is completed you should call callback where the first parameter is an error
             callback(null)

          })
          .catch(err => {
            // In case of an error callback with error
            callback(err)
          });
    }, function(err){
        // Your loop have completed
        if(err) {
            // The loop completed with an error, handle your error
        } else {
            // Your loop was completed successfully
            let searchObjectDocument = {
                name: "Games",
                results: arrayToFill
            }
            // As you can understand, right now the results key value is an empty array
            new SearchObject(searchObjectDocument).save();
            // ...
        }
    })
```

async is a great library, learning it will not hurt at all, in fact it will be very beneficial.

If you really don't want to use a third party library then your next bet would be to create promises array

Everytime you go inside the loop instead of doing `Game.findOne()...`
You would do a push into an array of promises.

Something like this **(KEEP IN MIND THIS IS NOT COMPLETE CODE, ITS JUST AN EXAMPLE)**

```
var promises = []
promises.push(Game.findOne()...)

// Then you do a promise.all
Promise.all(promises )
    .then(function(values) {
       // Everything was completed successfully
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
       // There was an error with one or all promises handle it here
    })
});
```

Don't forget to `resolve` and `reject` in each promise

This is a good article on [Medium](https://medium.com/dev-bits/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-32ed3a4fd098) regarding promises

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map instead of a for loop, inside the map returning a promise, and then after the map, do Promise.all(mapResult). This way promise.all will wait for every promise being resolved.

Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53982910/9661304